# How can I create page.tpl for user’s profile page?

Tags: 7, theming, users

Searching in Google I found user-profile.tpl.php , but in fact this is the node of profile page while I want to create page.tpl.php foe the profile page.
Also page-user.tpl.php includes login page, register page and all the pages belong to a user which I do not consider, I need to create page.tpl for profile page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the best way to handle this that i've come up with is a combination of 4 files:

- `page-user.tpl.php` for the far-back profile edit as igor said
- `user-profile.tpl.php` for the profile content
- `page-user-register.tpl.php` set to match page.tpl.php in order to keep
  page-user.tpl.php from overriding the register page, and
- `page-user-login.tpl.php` set up in the same way as page-user-register
  for the same reason.

Answer (score 4):

Try this...

```
page--user-profile.tpl.php
```

[page]--[node].tpl.php

or actually...

```
page--user.tpl.php
```

To see available templates for this page simply do the following in your themes template.php

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
   echo '<pre>'; var_dump($variables['theme_hook_suggestions']); echo '</pre>';
}
```

If nothing were in there (doubtful), then just add your own...

```
if ($SOME_CONDITION) {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page--user-profile.tpl.php';
}
```

Comment: The method of using preprocess and a theme hook suggestion is how I'd do it. +1