# Notice Error UND

Tags: 7, theming

I have a error that keeps popping up through my website after I added tags to print custom user profile fields. The code i'm using is

```
<?php 
global $user;
$user_fields = user_load($user->uid);
$name = $user_fields->field_name;
$department = $user_fields->field_department;
?>
<?php
```

to pint the fields i'm using

```
<?php print $name['und'][0]['value'];?>
<?php print $department['und'][0]['value'];?>
```

i'm not sure if this is the correct way to do this or if there is a better way. I tried to remove [0] and the tag no longer works. I have also tried to use the following:

```
  <?php if (!empty($action_links)): ?>
  <?php print $name['und'][0]['value'];?>
  <?php endif ?>
```

This again did not display the custom field.

Comment: Please if you run dpm($user_fields->field_name) and post results for all fields which you want to print?

As all fields don't have same structure as ['und'][0]['value'].

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you possibly elaborate a little further regarding this. I am fairly new to the drupal structure.

Comment: Install devel module. Than add following line to your code.


    dpm($user_fields->field_name); //where field_name is your user's field name.

It will print the structure of your field and you will be able to see that where is your value stored?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to print fields in Drupal 7 is to use [field_view_field()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_view_field/7) to fetch a renderable array that can be passed to [dupal_render()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_render/7) like so:

```
<?php
  global $user;
  $user = user_load($user->uid);
  print drupal_render(field_view_field('user', $user, 'field_name'));
  print drupal_render(field_view_field('user', $user, 'field_department'));
?>
```

This is also true for $node objects FYI.

Comment: how do I print them out using your code?

Comment: I don't follow your question; printing is included in the code above.

Comment: I put the following code into my template and it doesn't print anything. I'm sorry if i'm missing something.

Comment: What template file are you using? Are your fields profile2 fields, or "regular" user fields? Have you cleared your caches?

Comment: I'm just using regular old user fields. Not using profile2 fields or anything like that. I created a template file for the user profile page i'm using so I named the file page--user.tpl.php

Comment: Make sure you're using the proper template file as per http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52247/how-can-i-create-page-tpl-for-user-s-profile-page, and be sure to clear your caches every time you add a new template file.

Comment: i'm using the profile template page according to your link. i'm not sure why its not working correctly.

Comment: I forgot the user_load()...updated my code. I just verified this code works in page--user.tpl.php

Comment: user load? can you show can example?

Comment: The code I added above should work exactly how it's written.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to render the field as drupal would in the "manage display" then use Webdrips answer.  If you are simple wanting to render the value and have the entity API then you can do this:

```
<?php 
  global $user;
  $user = user_load($user->uid);
  $user_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $user);
  $name = $user_wrapper->field_name->value();
  $department = $user_wrapper->field_department->value();
?>
<?php
  print $name;
  print $department;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the warnings because you are accessing any `indexes` that are not present in that field.  Mainly occurres when these fields are not entered so these indexes are not created. You can use it with the isset to avoid these `error/warnings`

```
<?php print isset($name['und'][0]['value']) ? $name['und'][0]['value'] : "";?>
<?php print isset($department['und'][0]['value']) ? $department['und'][0]['value'] "";?>
```

OR

You can use the default drupal method to print field using field_view_field() function as mention in the earlier answer.

```
<?php
global $user;
$userFull = user_load($user->uid);
print render(field_view_field('user',$userFull,'field_name',$display=array() ));
//Where $display handles the label(hidden or to show), format etc
?>
```

Hope it will help!