# Change content location in node template

Tags: theming, users

My content is normally displayed in a specific region that takes up 75% of the screen width, which is usually desired.
However on 'User Profile' pages (and a few others) I want it to take 100% of the width.

I created a user-profile.tpl.php file, which contains the content wrapped in a div that takes up the full screen width using bootstrap like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <?php print render($user_profile); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

The content is rendered, but it's wrapped in the normal content region that is only 75% of the width.  This is a simplified version of the content that is rendered:

```
<div class="col-md-9 content-region">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <?php print render($user_profile); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just disable whatever you have in the sidebar for those pages?

Comment: What's in the sidebar is already disabled, but since I'm using Twitter Bootstrap the columns are set to only take up that much space even if the other columns are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change the page-user.tpl.php to be able to remove the class from the content region. see here [How can I create page.tpl for user’s profile page?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52247/how-can-i-create-page-tpl-for-user-s-profile-page)

Answer (score 1):

You could set the classes in hook_preprocess, and switch them based on if there is sidebar content or not.

Here is an example I do in a theme that I made which accomplishes this:

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_html().
 * @param array $variables
 */
function STARTER_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  if (!empty($variables['page']['sidebar_first'])) {
    $sidebar_left = $variables['page']['sidebar_first'];
  }

  if (!empty($variables['page']['sidebar_second'])) {
    $sidebar_right = $variables['page']['sidebar_second'];
  }

  // Dynamic sidebars.
  if (!empty($sidebar_left) && !empty($sidebar_right)) {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'two-sidebars';
  }
  elseif (empty($sidebar_left) && !empty($sidebar_right)) {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'one-sidebar';
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'sidebar-second';
  }
  elseif (!empty($sidebar_left) && empty($sidebar_right)) {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'one-sidebar';
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'sidebar-first';
  }
  else {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'no-sidebars';
  }
}
```

These sidebar classes map back to grid widths in the SCSS, the same could be done with Bootstrap by just throwing in col- classes.

When set as no-sidebars, the grid is full width. You could also add in more classes based on the page type, but I would opt to go this route in case you actually want something on the sidebar in the future on a user profile. You won't have to change any code, it will just react to content being present.

Comment: to be more precise if sidebar-second is empty I'd like sidebar-first to have the 'col-md-12' class, and and if not I'd like it to have the 'col-md-9' class

Comment: You can still use similar checks then, and add on to the classes array for content-region. Is content-region a real region, or is that just a CSS class and nothing else?

Comment: The main page content is being put into a content region called 'primary' I'd like to be able to do something like $variables['attributes']['class']['primary'] = 'col-md-12'; If possible. If this is not possible I suppose I can always just add some checks in php and add the classes in the template based on what classes everything is inside of.

Comment: Is there not a classes array on $variables['page']['content_region']?

Comment: I guess that's what I'm trying to find. I've used $variables['page']['myregion']['classes'] = 'col-md-12'; and several other combinations with no luck.

Comment: You should use a debugger to inspect the $variables array so you can see what options are available to you instead of guessing. I would recommend xdebug in an IDE or https://www.drupal.org/project/devel to dump the variables and exit.